# Turn off word wrap on Github split diff viewer

Tags: github

I've looked everywhere in the settings in Github and found nothing where I can take the word-wrap off on GitHub. Every time I google it, I never get answers about GitHub specifically because google thinks I'm looking for repositories that have this issue or something so it like gives me stuff like issues and Pull Requests.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:[image: sample diff of word wrap on GitHub]

The fact that it wraps makes it practically unreadable to me. Does anyone know of a way to turn this off?

The weird thing is that both Team Foundation Server and Github are owned by Microsoft and TFS has no word wrap, so you'd think Github would at least have the ability to toggle it off.

Comment: FWIW, I opened a support ticket with them about 2 months ago regarding this and got this response _"We have forwarded your ticket to the Product team who reads and evaluates all feedback, however we cannot guarantee a response to every submission."_  and not a word from them since.

Comment: Can you link the support ticket you put in? Is it a feature request?
It's not as though right now I can't just use VS code to view the commit history and stuff, but I would much rather prefer to view the diffed files online.

Comment: I can link it, but it would 404 for you since tickets are private.

Comment: Thanks, brother. I was thinking more of like an issue I could follow rather than a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is write github and request the feature.

I agree, sometimes it's better not to wrap. When not wrapping though I prefer a UI that keeps both sides in sync while horizontally scrolling.

[image]

Comment: whats the tool in the picture?